# How to add fullcallendar to a laravel app

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, metronic

I am trying to integrate fullcallendar in a laravel10 + Metronic app

`helpers.addVendors(['fullcalendar']);` called from controller gives error:

`Undefined constant "App\Http\Controllers\helpers"` 
CODE:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        helpers.addVendors(['fullcalendar']);

        return view('pages/calendar')->with(['page'=>'calendar','section'=>'this_month']);
    }
}
```

How to add assets from controller? Documentation isn't that clear.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a php syntax, you should use it in your view as JS I would say

Answer (score 1):

I found it by myself. What you got to do is go to `laravel_app/config/global/pages.php` and add this to the main array :

```
'calendar' => array(
'title'  => 'Calendar modified',
'assets' => array(
    'custom' => array(
        'css' => array(
            'plugins/custom/flatpickr/flatpickr.bundle.css',
            'plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.css',
            'plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.css',
        ),

        'js' => array(
            'plugins/custom/flatpickr/flatpickr.bundle.js',
            'plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js',
            'plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js',

            'js/custom/apps/calendar/mycalendar.js',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Create a route

```
// calendar
Route::get('/calendar', [CalendarController::class, 'index']);
```

Create a controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages/calendar')->with(['page'=>'calendar','section'=>'this_month']);
    }
}
```

Create `calendar.blade.php` in `laravel_app/resources/views/pages/` and add calendar and modals from the demo1 calendar.html

That is all, hope it helps others, as the Metronic documentation on laravel is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should never add assets from your controller. Code you used is not PHP/laravel code, so it won't work.

You should always add assets in your blade file, in this case with script tag like this:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.7/index.global.min.js'></script>
```

Then you can use fullcalendar as it's official documentation suggests https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals

Comment: the thing is that i am using Metronic and i have to use exactly this calendar: https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/apps/calendar.html

Comment: "_You should never add assets from your controller_" Why not?